# Dependency injection with Autofac, MVC5 and OWIN not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, autofac, owin

I am having difficulties integrating Autofac with MVC5 and Owin. It seems that MVC is skipping AutofacMvc integration and is still using System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory to instantiate a controller, thus throwing

```
No parameterless constructor defined for this object
```

There's a great article from 
Alex Meyer-Gleaves on [setting up Owin support for MVC 5 integrations in Autofac](http://alexmg.com/owin-support-for-the-web-api-2-and-mvc-5-integrations-in-autofac/). I have followed that, and downloaded packages, but still not working. Here's what my Startup.cs looks like:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{ 
    var container = AutofacConfig.Register();
    app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);  // 1 - setting up autofac middleware (Autofac.Integration.Owin.dll)
    app.UseAutofacMvc(); // 2 - passing on life time scope created in Owin onto MVC request (Autofac.Integration.Mvc.Owin)
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container)); // 3 - setting dependency resolver for MVC (Autofac.Integration.Mvc)
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

I have checked that my service was registered, my route is invoked successfully if I remove service parameter from constructor. What else I might be missing? Any hints where the problem might lie would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, the problem lied in the fact that I forgot to register controllers into Autofac. adding this line solved the problem:

```
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

Comment: I did add this and still the problem persists. I have registered both ApiController and Controller as 
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());            builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).PropertiesAutowired();